# How to use a non-WordPress user session to access WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, single-sign-on

I am trying to use my current sessions inside WordPress.  I have an existing website built using PHP that is a non-WordPress site, and now I want to add a blog feature on my website, and I think WordPress is the best platform for the job.

My problem is that I have existing users that are non-WordPress, and I don't want to register my existing users one by one into WordPress. I don't want to import my existing users table into WordPress if a new member is added.

Is there any way to use my current user session inside WordPress?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=3991#p51165

Comment: And this one: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53082/login-in-wordpress-using-external-database-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to make this possible by creating two plugins in wordpress the first one is referencing a existing plugin [ext_db_auth](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/external-database-authentication/trunk/ext_db_auth.php?order=name) and the other one is using below code referencing [here](https://silvermapleweb.com/using-the-php-session-in-wordpress/).

Hope this will be useful for those who are seeking for the same functionality.

```
add_action('init', 'myStartSession', 1);
add_action('wp_logout', 'myEndSession');
add_action('wp_login', 'myEndSession');

function myStartSession() {
    if(!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
}

function myEndSession() {
    session_destroy ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must import your user's table to WordPress users.

The best practice its to convert your site to WordPress theme.

But if it's heavy for you, you have more option as follow, In order of priorities in descending order:

1. Import users and change from now the login to wp-login.
2. Import users but use [wp_signon](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_signon/) function.
3. Use your regular site header and footer instead WordPress header & footer.